# how do I proceed further in this integration?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

**Question** : let $n$ be a positive integer. For a real number $x$ , let $[x]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding $x$ and $F=x-[x]$ then I have to prove  $$\int_1^{n+1}\frac{F^{[x]}}{[x]}dx=\dfrac{n}{n+1}$$
**my attempt** : I write $$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_1^{n+1}\frac{F^{[x]}}{[x]}dx &=&\int_1^{2}\frac{F^{[x]}}{[x]}dx+\int_2^{3}\frac{F^{[x]}}{[x]}dx+. . . . . . +\int_n^{n+1}\frac{F^{[x]}}{[x]}dx\\  
&=& \sum_{r=1}^n\int_r^{r+1}\frac{F^{[x]}}{[x]}dx\\  
&=& \sum_{r=1}^n\int_r^{r+1}\frac{(x-r)^r}{[r]}dx\\  
&=& \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r^2+r}\\
\end{eqnarray}$$ .
But how I can prove this equals $\frac{n}{n+1}$ ? How I proceed further?

Comment: Can you see a telescopic term in your final sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r^2+r}=\sum_{r=1}^n\Big(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\Big)\\
=(1-1/2)+(1/2-1/3)+...+(1/(n)-(1/(n+1)))=1-1/(n+1)=n/(n+1)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:-

$\frac{1}{r^2+r}=\frac{1}{r(r+1)}=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r^2+r}=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r(r+1)}=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}$